# How to style the h2 title of "search results"?

Tags: views

The "search results" H2 element on the search results page does not appear to be controlled by any specific template. I'm using stable9 as the base. How can I style it?

[image]

Comment: `form.search-form h2` or form alter the particular form in question and edit that element to have a class on the markup.

Comment: `<h2>Search results</h2>` is not part of the search form. The full search page is rendered by a controller, so `hook_form_alter()` would not help.

Comment: It’s next to the form, though, and CSS has sibling selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a template file for that `<h2>` element because it is not rendered using a theme implementation, but from [`SearchController::view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Controller%21SearchController.php/function/SearchController%3A%3Aview/9), which uses the following code.

```php
  if (count($results)) {
    $build['search_results_title'] = [
      '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
    ];
  }
  $build['search_results'] = [
    '#theme' => [
      'item_list__search_results__' . $plugin->getPluginId(),
      'item_list__search_results',
    ],
    '#items' => $results,
    '#empty' => [
      '#markup' => '<h3>' . $this->t('Your search yielded no results.') . '</h3>',
    ],
    '#list_type' => 'ol',
    '#context' => [
      'plugin' => $plugin->getPluginId(),
    ],
  ];
```

The part of that method that renders the search form is the following one.

```php
$build['search_form'] = $this->formBuilder()->getForm(SearchPageForm::class, $entity);
```

`$build['search_results_title']` is not part of the `$build['search_form']` form, so implementing `hook_form_alter()` (or one of its variations) would not help. Attaching CSS styles to the page with `hook_page_attachments()` that target that `<h2>` element would not be possible without targeting all the `<h2>` elements in that page (or other pages) as Drupal core does not add specific classes to `<h2>Search results</h2>`.

The only possibility I see is changing the route callback used for that page, as described in [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones), keeping in mind that the route for the node search page is *search.view_node*, which is defined in [`SearchPageRoutes::routes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Routing%21SearchPageRoutes.php/function/SearchPageRoutes%3A%3Aroutes/9) as:

```php
    $routes["search.view_{$entity_id}"] = new Route('/search/' . $entity->getPath(), [
      '_controller' => 'Drupal\\search\\Controller\\SearchController::view',
      '_title' => 'Search',
      'entity' => $entity_id,
    ], [
      '_entity_access' => 'entity.view',
      '_permission' => 'search content',
    ], [
      'parameters' => [
        'entity' => [
          'type' => 'entity:search_page',
        ],
      ],
    ]);
```

The controller method that renders that page is [`SearchController::view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Controller%21SearchController.php/function/SearchController%3A%3Aview/9). You can look at its code to understand what it is expected to render/do.